# Pointers In Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios4, pointers

How do I compare two pointers in objective C without using the compare operator "isEqualToString"? Please help if any alternate.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to do? Compare if two objects are equals?

Answer (score 5):

If you really want to compare two pointers in objc (which I doubt) you could use the standard "==" operator.

```
if(mypointer1==mypointer2){}
```

By the way, doing so you are not comparing the data of the objects pointed by the pointers, but simply the numeric value of the pointers itself (aka their address).

If you want to compare two objects you could use (if they implement it)

`isEqual`. Finally, if you are comparing two strings, you should use

`isEqualToString:`

Comment: I need to know weather the two pointers has the same value or not?

Comment: what exactly do you mean with "value"? you mean memory address?

Comment: no for example in string1 = @"xyz" & string 2 = @"yxz" so now i dont know the string value in it so for that i am trying to compare the two pointers.

Comment: you could use "compare" and expect a NSOrderedSame in case they are equal. But I'm sorry, I'm not sure to understand what you are asking here

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to chime to clarify that the use of 
str1==str2 
will (correctly) tell you if the pointer (technically references in objc) are equal.

However (starting in iOS 8.x (and possibly earlier)), you will get a warning stating that the result is "undefined"